# Namespace not available in other project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, namespaces, c#-3.0

I have created one C# console application. In that application, I have many namespaces.

for example :

```
namespace com.xyz.foo.bar
{
}

namespace com.xyz.abc.def
{
}
```

When I added reference of this console application into an WCF service project, some of the namespaces are not available for import. i.e. from above example I can get `com.xyz.foo.bar` namespace but `com.xyz.abc.def` namespace is not available.

I dont understand why this is happening.

If I open executable of console application from 'object browser' I can see all the namespaces.

Can anyone explain the reason behind this thing??

Comment: Is there any differences in their content ? Both have public classes available ?

Comment: @Matthiue, both namespaces have 1 or more public classes. com.xyz.abc.def namespace have one public class with main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where a namespace was not found even though there was a project reference in the same solution, types were public, etc..

It turned out that I needed to change the "Target Framework" to be ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile".  I didn't bother figuring out why this resulted in an "unknown namespace" error, but it solved my problem.

John

Comment: I will try it out once I am in office.

Answer (score 1):

Your namespaces must have classes etc marked as `public`

```
namespace com.xyz.foo.bar
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}

namespace com.xyz.abc.def
{
    public class AnotherClass
    {
    }
}
```

`bar` namespace will not be visible while `def` will (if nothing else is declared with `public` in them)

Comment: I have public class in com.xyz.foo.bar namespace but then also that entire namespace is not available. Why do namespace needs to have public class?