# Can't access public classes in an other project but the same namespace

Tags: c#

I have two projects in my solution and in each of them I have a CS file containing a public class. Since both classes are in the same namespace, I was expecting them to be able to see each other. That is not the case. See the setup below.

Project Woof1, file File.CS

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  public class Foo
  {
    // Doesn't compile
    Faa f;
  }
}
```

Project Woof2, file File.CS

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  public class Faa
  {
    // Doesn't compile
    Foo f;
  }
}
```

NB, both classes are stored in files with the same name **but** in different directories (i.e. not the same file).

1. Why can't I compile it?
2. What can I do about it (except moving the classes to the same project).

*(I only found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040123/namespace-not-available-in-other-project) on the subject but in the end it wasn't really my issue.)*

Comment: The first thing that comes in my mind is a missing reference. Even if the projects are in the same solution, project Woof2 needs a reference to project Woof1.

Comment: I think both of your projects need reference to each other.

Comment: you have to add a project reference to Woof1 inside Woof2. Right click references and select Woof2 from same solution. FYI the namespaces are case sensitive. MyNameSpace is typed differently but i presume this is only a typo for your example right?

Comment: Is this the real code? Because your 2 namespace aren't the same.

Comment: @Johnny5 Yes, I added the references. I've tried both project reference AND the DLL as well. And yes - it was a type in the namespace but only on SO. In the real code, it was spelled correctly.

Comment: What else do you have in the files? Are there any other classes or structures declared? Accessing those, by any chance? The example you've provided should work given that you're referencing right stuff and that the structures you're trying to access are public. I saw some guy telling you that it's a circle reference and can't be done. He doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: I just realized the problem. I thought `enum` was public by default. I haven't set my enumerator definitions to `public`. That was the low point of the day... Someone put it as an asnwer so I can check it done.

Comment: You're coming from C++, aren't you? You were thinking about `struct` versus `class`, right? `struct` is by default a publicly scoped gizmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure the references are set up as supposed to. Each project needs to refer to the other.
2. Make sure to set `public` qualifier on **all** the classes in the projects.
3. Make sure to set `public` qualifier on **all** the enumerations in the projects.

Also, preferably, you might want to move your `enum`s and other auxiliary definitions to a common project and store them there.

Comment: And please note that circular dependencies like this should be avoided. So the best part of the answer is creating the extra shared assembly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is there **any** case when it's necessary to keep circular references? I was going to put **that** in my answer but then I got unsure. Perhaps the guy has some really weird set up that **does** require such approach. Can you think of any?

Comment: I have seen it happen, but always due to a bad design. I can't think of any legitimate case. But I suppose it could happen in complicated libs, like maybe .NET itself. I'm thinking about apps here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to project Woof1 from project Woof2.

Also, trying to reference both from each other is not a great idea as you introduce a circular dependancy, making builds a nightmare.  If ever you fell you need to do this, you should consider factoring common code out into a separate (third) project.

Answer (score 2):

In Woof1 you need to include a reference to Woof2.
Another thing to note is that the namespace is case-sensitive, so both namespaces should be MyNameSpace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a project reference to Woof1 from project Woof2. Please reference to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I did happen with me.It might  comes if dlls are not proper builds.In my case i was using release option in toolbar.So make sure that debug option is selected