# Namespace from other projects not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution with 4 projects with these namespaces:

### project name TPCO

> namespace TPCO
>   namespace TPCO.Controllers
>   namespace TPCO.Models

### project name TPCO.Core

> namespace TPCO.Core.Data
>   namespace TPCO.Core.Domain
>   namespace TPCO.Core.Models

### project name TPCO.Data

> namespace TPCO.Data

### project name TPCO.Tests

> namespace TPCO.Tests.Controllers

The TPCO.Core and TPCO.Data projects were originally part of an ASP.Net Web Application. I imported them into an ASP.Net MVC5 application solution containing the TPCO and TPCO.Test projects.

For some reason, I cannot see any of the namespaces from TPCO.Core or TPCO.Data from TPCO. I also cannot see TPCO, TPCO.Controllers or TPCO.Models from TPCO.Core or TPCO.Data projects. However, I can see TPCO.Core.* from TPCO.Data and vice versa.

And from TPCO.Tests, I can only see the namespaces from the TPCO and TPCO.Tests projects.

All projects have same target framework, per:  [Namespace not available in other project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040123/namespace-not-available-in-other-project)
Also, ALL classes in TPCO.Core and TPCO.Data are marked `public`

What is going on and how do I remedy this? Could it be that the TPCO.Core and TPCO.Data projects reside outside the folder structure of the MVC app that is causing this?

Comment: Check how the projects reference each other. They should be set up as project references. If they are set as dll references then VS is looking for the compiled dll in a specific folder.

Comment: Man, how could I forget that? post as answer, please.

Comment: Ok, I've copied and pasted as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how the projects reference each other. They should be set up as project references. If they are set as dll references then VS is looking for the compiled dll in a specific folder.

I think the easiest way to check this is by opening the .csproj in notepad. Find the ItemGroup for the reference and ensure it is a project.

Project Reference:

```
  <ProjectReference Include="..\DataInterface\DataInterface.csproj">
    <Project>{b0c3500f-6d72-46f5-a8e9-5283fa116db2}</Project>
    <Name>DataInterface</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
```

DLL Reference:

```
  <Reference Include="DataInterface">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\Dlls\DataInterface.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

Then, if it is a dll reference, remove it from the project's references and add it back in as a project reference.